# Multiple records saves with same id in firebase in react application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, observable

I am currently learning react-redux and developing a simple application. When I am going to create new category the records save with same category_id like below.

```
categories
 -KpKwhwyuXtq1uFkE56K
    category_id: "1"
    desc: "title 1 desc"
    title: "title 1"
 -KpL2mWBrzP_36wrDQs6
   category_id: "1"
   desc: "title 2 desc"
   title: "title 2"
 -KpLHaNkSNbqimTJ59Mi
   category_id: "1"
   desc: "title 3 desc"
   title: "title 3"
```

here category_id needs to be unique. I have used following solution but not able to get unique category_id.

CategoryNew.jsx:

```
handleUpdate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = this.title.value.trim();
    var desc = this.desc.value.trim();

    this.props.categoryUpdate({
      title: title,
      desc: desc
    }, this.props.match.params.category_id);
    this.title.value = "";
    this.desc.value = "";

    setTimeout(function () { window.location.replace("/"); }, 10)
  }
render() {
    const { categoriesId, categories } = this.props;
    var categoriesArr = categoriesId.map(id => (Object.assign({}, categories[id], {category_id: id})))
    console.log('Category ids array', categoriesArr);

    var category_id = this.state.category_id;
    var title = this.props.categories.title;
    var desc = this.props.categories.desc;

        return (
      <Panel>
        <form onSubmit={ category_id ? this.handleUpdate.bind(this) : this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <h3>{category_id ? "Edit category" : "Create a New Category"}</h3>
          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsText">
            <ControlLabel>Title</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              inputRef={ref => {
                this.title = ref;
              }}
              placeholder="Enter title"
              defaultValue={title}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsTextarea">
            <ControlLabel>Description</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="textarea"
              defaultValue={desc}
              inputRef={ref => {
                this.desc = ref;
              }}
              placeholder="Enter description"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button className="btn-primary" type="submit">
            {category_id ? "Update" : "Submit"}
          </Button>
          <span>  </span>
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel </Link>
        </form>
      </Panel>
        );
    }
}
unction mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    categoriesId: state.categoriesState.ids,
    categories: state.categoriesState.categories,
    //categories: state.categoriesState.selectedCategory,
    formloaded: state.postsState.formloaded
  };
}  

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
  newCategoryCreate, 
  selectedCategory,
  categoryUpdate
})(CategoriesNew);
```

reducer.jsx:

```
   import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'; 
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      ids: [],
      categories: {}, 
      selected_category: {},
      isFetchingCategories: false,
      isFetchingSingleCategories: false,
      formloaded: false
    };

  case actionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORIES:
      return { ...state };
  case actionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state,formloaded: true };
```

epics.jsx:

```
import AdminService from '../../../app/admin/services/AdminService';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';
import * as categoryActions from './actions';

export const newCategoryCreate = (action$,{ getJSON } ) => {
  return action$.ofType(actionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORIES)
    .map( action => action.payload)
    .switchMap((category) => AdminService.categorySubmit(category))
    .map(category => categoryActions.fetchCategoriesSuccess(Object.values(category)))   
}
```

actions.jsx:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export function newCategoryCreate(props) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORIES,
    payload: props
  };
}
export function newCategoryCreateSuccess(props) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
    payload: props
  };
}
```

AdminService.jsx:

```
 static categorySubmit(category){
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('categories');
    firebaseRef.push(category);
    this.getCategories();
    return Observable.of(category);
  }
```

Please suggest me where I am going wrong and how I can solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the firebase id as the category id. It is not clear where you are setting the category id in the above code. But just by looking at the sample firebase output, I can say that the `category_id` should be same as the firebase id.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing me out. It works fine after setting category_id as firebase id.